# Updating a many to many collection with EF code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I'm using EF Code First with the following configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
        .HasMany(x => x.TeamLeaders)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UserId")
        .MapRightKey("TeamLeaderId")
        .ToTable("UserTeamLeaders"));
}
```

TeamLeaders is an ICollection of Users i.e. it is a self referencing many-many relationship.

In plain English, a user can have more than one team leader. This configuration appears to be correct, as it creates the duel FK/PK link table as I would expect.

I have an MVC4 application that allows editing, adding and removal of team leaders from the collection.

In my controller, I originally had the following:

```
    var original = context.UserProfiles
        .Include("TeamLeaders")
        .Single(x => x.UserId == model.UserId);

    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
```

However, that last line was failing to mark the TeamLeaders collection as updated, and when I called SaveChanges(), no changes were recorded.

Instead I wrote a simple CopyProperties method on my User class, which uses reflection to manually copy the properties across, so in my controller I now have:

```
    var original = context.UserProfiles
        .Include("TeamLeaders")
        .Single(x => x.UserId == model.UserId);

    //context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);

    original.CopyProperties(model);
```

However, this goes too far, and SaveChanges attempts to add a new user to the system matching the profile of the selected team leader.

Can anyone advise as to which part of this I am doing wrong? I am not sure whether I need to update the mappings, or change the way I copy properties from the view model to the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must modify the loaded `TeamLeaders` collection in the `original` user according to your changes so that change detection can recognize which leaders have been removed and which have been added. When you call `SaveChanges` then EF will write the appropriate DELETE and INSERT statements for the join table based on the detected changes. The simplest way would look like this:

```
var original = context.UserProfiles
    .Include("TeamLeaders")
    .Single(x => x.UserId == model.UserId);

original.TeamLeaders.Clear();
foreach (var teamLeader in model.TeamLeaders)
{
    var user = context.UserProfiles.Find(teamLeader.UserId);
    if (user != null)
        original.TeamLeaders.Add(user)
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

`Find` will fetch the team leaders from the context if they are already loaded. If they aren't loaded it will query the database.

If you want to avoid additional queries you can attach the team leaders manually to the context:

```
var original = context.UserProfiles
    .Include("TeamLeaders")
    .Single(x => x.UserId == model.UserId);

original.TeamLeaders.Clear();
foreach (var teamLeader in model.TeamLeaders)
{
    var user = context.UserProfiles.Local
        .SingleOrDefault(o => o.UserId == teamLeader.UserId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        user = new User { UserId = teamLeader.UserId };
        context.UserProfiles.Attach(user);
    }
    original.TeamLeaders.Add(user)
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Except the first query to load the `original` here is no further database query involved.

BTW: You should be able to use the strongly typed `Include` version with EF Code First:

```
Include(u => u.TeamLeaders)
```

You just need `using System.Data.Entity;` in your code file to get access to this version.

Comment: Thank you for this - works a treat. I would have preferred not to have to clear / re-add in the controller - instead it would be nice if there were a way of setting it up so that it works it out for itself with some simple config / attributes on the model / mapping, but this works so I will stick with this for now.

Comment: @GGG: Unfortunately updating detached object graphs is always quite a bit of code to write. There is no configuration option which would simplify the work. `CurrentValues.SetValues(model)` only affects scalar properties, it doesn't update any navigation property, as you have seen in your first try.