# Entity Framework Table Per Class/Type, Many To Many relationship between derived classes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, abstract

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Approver
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String ApproverName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Role")]
public class Role : Approver
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
} 

[Table("User")]    
public class User : Approver
{
    [Required]
    public virtual String Email { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public virtual String Password { get; set; }

    public virtual String FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual String LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
{
```

The following code is in the OnModelCreating() method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(e=>e.Roles).WithMany(e=>e.Users);
```

The error when running the 'Update-Database' command is:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.MappingException: 
>   (11,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 11, 966:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to two overlapping groups of rows.
>
> (11,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 6, 11:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to the same group of rows.
>
> (966,6) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 6, 966:Two rows with different primary keys are mapped to the same entity. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with identical keys to two overlapping groups of rows.

There seems to be a similar known problem (at least till EF5), not exactly the same scenario, mentioned [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1232) and [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1289).

Any insight would be valuable.

UPDATE:

The problem seems to be in adding the entities to the DB. In the Seed method as follows (much simplified, here I am just adding Roles):

```
    GetDefaultUsersAndRoles(out defaultUsers, out roleNames);

            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                Role roleToAdd = new Role
                {
                    ApproverName = roleName
                };

                context.Roles.Add(roleToAdd);
             }

             context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a many to many collection with EF code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445991/updating-a-many-to-many-collection-with-ef-code-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. It was a foreign-key mapping issue:

```
                modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<Role>(r => r.Roles).WithMany(u => u.Users);
```